# How to remove "org.restlet.engine.application.StatusInfo" on JSON response

Tags: java, rest, restlet

A typical Restlet error message looks like this:

```
{
  "org.restlet.engine.application.StatusInfo": {
    "code": 400,
    "description": "ID cannot be empty or null",
    "homeRef": "/",
    "reasonPhrase": "Bad Request",
    "uri": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1"
  }
}
```

Is there away to remove the `org.restlet.engine.application.StatusInfo` part?

Comment: Could you give us the code you used to create your error message? Thanks!